# weird behavior caused by parenthesis () in c++

Tags: c++

It is quite confusing that `()` caused unexpected behavior. I thought there is no difference in c++ that `()` is also used to group an expression. It seems that I am wrong in the following example. **Could you explain how this happened?**

**Example 1**
In this example, everything seems to work fine. It returns a correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    string s = "abcd";
    string ret = "";
    int i = 0;
    ret = ret + "<b>" + s[i];
    cout << ret << endl;
}
```

**Example 2**
The only difference from example one is that a pair of `()` is added in `ret = ret + "<b>" + s[i];`. Then it runs successfully, but nothing has been returned in my local IDE, on leetcode web, it even throws an error `Char 30: runtime error: index 97 out of bounds for type 'const char [4]' (solution.cpp) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:24:30`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    string s = "abcd";
    string ret = "";
    int i = 0;
    ret = ret + ("<b>" + s[i]);
    cout << ret << endl;
}
```

**Example 3**
This example behaves like example 2. Nothing has been returned.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    string s = "abcd";
    string ret = "";
    int i = 0;
    ret += "<b>" + s[i];
    cout << ret << endl;
}
```

Comment: Types matter, and a string literal isn't a `std::string`.

Comment: This is exactly the same reason why `2 * 3 + 4` will not give you the same result as `2  * (3 + 4)`. Except that in C++ the wrong one [makes demons fly out of your nose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon).

Comment: `("<b>" + s[i])` -- Let's ask you -- what data type will this result in?  It isn't `std::string`.

Comment: @EOF thank you very much. I come from a background in python. I will look in ````a string literal isn't a std::string````

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't know for sure, but I expect a string type from ````("<b>" + s[i])````

Comment: Why do you expect a `std::string`? "<b>" is not a `std::string`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I apologize for my lack of knowledge in c++. But why is "<b>" not of string type? I mean it is under double quotes, right?

Comment: You are adding a string-literal, i.e. an address, to a `char` value.  There is no telling what that result will be if you printed it.

Comment: Yes. It's because it is a `const char *`. Which is not the same thing as a `std::string`. Double quotes in C++ evaluate to a `const char *` type, a pointer to a constant character. This is all explained in a C++ textbook. It is not very efficient to learn C++ by trial and error, like that. C++ is too complicated. A textbook is required to learn core C++ fundamentals.

Comment: I just tried `auto s1 = ("<b>" + s[0]);`, printed it out in Visual Studio.  What is printed is the directory to one of my include files.  There you go.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that is super weird! But I got no return in CLion IDE.

Comment: @AlbertGLieu Something was "returned".  Maybe it was null bytes, maybe it was a bunch of non-printables, etc.  Also `std::string` is not a native type -- it is a standard C++ class that handles character data.  If you look at the `<string>` header, you will see the implementation.  It isn't something built into C++ as it is for other languages.

Comment: If you want the string literal `"<b>"` to be a std::string (so you get all the *chocolatey goodness* of std::string object), you can use `"<b>"s` or `string("<b>")`.

Comment: @raneshu *None of these comments actually answer the question.* -- That is because the comment section is for comments, not answers.  Answers go in the answer section.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - the comments section is intended for clarifying a question/making suggestions leading to an answer. Not for condescending or discouraging comments.

Comment: @raneshu In the question itself, this is stated -- `but nothing has been returned in my local IDE,` -- And this was explained in the comments as to why that is, and that the results can really be anything.  So thanks for saying I wasted my time showing what happens on another compiler.  The OP isn't complaining...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  happy holidays Pual, thank you very much. I learned a lot from these comments. Sincerely appreciate your efforts in teaching me. raneshu, I don't find any comments discouraging. Instead, I think they all points me in the right direction. Giving somebody a fish rod is better than giving him a fish.

Answer (score 1):

string literals automatically turn into pointers in some circumstances (all array types do this).

so when you have

```cpp
string s = "";

s + "test";
```

this actually calls the `operator+(string&, char*)` that neatly copies and appends the characters from `char*` to `string` until the `\0` character (strings usually end with `\0` to signify end of string).

but when you do

```cpp
string a = "a";

"test" + a[0];
```

you call `operator+(char*, char)` which adds the numerical value of `char` to the `char*`, which shifts where `char*` is pointing to by 97 bytes (97 is the numerical representation of character a in this case).

alternatively you could write:

```
"test"[a[0]]
```

which would have the exact same effect.

Comment: what is the a in ````a[0]````, which seems to be undefined?

Comment: that was a typo
it's just supposed to be a string with character `a` in it